# How to handle error messages in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Im developing Angular 7 app and I wonder what is the best way to handle errors.
I Think that best practice will be to handle them all in one place. 
So json response from the server contains error message and HTTP error messages will reach the same place so I don't need to handle every error in his component/service.

I've created HTTP error interceptor that works as expected, but I also want to add error messages coming from Json error response to show them in the same view and write to log.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the error messages? Is it for logging purposes? Or are you planning to display some kind of message indicating an error on the view?

Comment: To show the error in a view, to write to a log file would also be great

Comment: If you want to show the error on the view, you will have to handle it on the subscribe callback on the component. If you are not familiar with that, I will write it on the answer below since I will need some space to explain it

Comment: Yes, but I rather avoid the same logic for every component that need to show the same error view. Ideally I would want to send different error message from each component and to have one place that show the error in a view on top of the current component.

Comment: I see.. I'm sorry I can't help you with that then! You can write some kind of directive, but that will still require you to inject/import it into your component..

Comment: @BoazGarty I think you have to use `notificationService`. messages and status manage with `API` response.